# link button enable after adding boostrap js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

in my asp.net web page i used link buttons inside a repeater.
after i adding boostrap.js files it will disable the link buttons in side the repeater how can i solve this issue

```
this is my Javascripts
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../App_Themes/DefaultTheme/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../App_Themes/DefaultTheme/js/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../App_Themes/DefaultTheme/js/bootstrap-multiselect-collapsible-groups.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../App_Themes/DefaultTheme/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Place your full code

Comment: By the way, you are loading jquery twice

Comment: I didn't understand how to use j query

Comment: please upload your code where the repeating links are placed